# Simple diffraction on periodic structures

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, photon-emission

I am trying to understand diffraction on periodic structured in solid state physics.

[image]

Q is the source of the spherical wave. R the vector to the object and R+r the vector to the scattering centre P, which gives us a another spherical wave.

All spherical waves are considered as plane waves due to the big distance between P,B and Q.

The magnitude at P can be described as: $\Psi_P(t) = \Psi_0e^{i(\vec k (\vec R + \vec r)-\omega_0 t)}$

My questions:

1. The magnitude on point Q, which means $\vec R + \vec r = 0$, is only depending on the time $t$ in $e^{-i\omega_0 t}$. My book(Ibach, Lueth Festkörperphysik) says that it has a fixed phase anytime. According to wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave#Complex_exponential_form) the phase $\varphi$ is included in $\Psi_0$. **What does it mean to have a "fixed phase" especially at location Q?**
2. "You can only use this plane wave approach $\Psi_B$ for *a* emission process." my book says, but why is it so?
3. "In real emitters do atoms send many photons with uncorrelated phases. (Exception: lasers)" my book also says. Does that mean the phase of the different photos are independent to each other?